# How could I cannect to application developed in wordpress and codeigniter?

Tags: wordpress, web-services, codeigniter

I have my website and some registration form in word press while i have new admin of self service panel in codeigniter. Now i want to connect these to application.  Please help us hoe could i make this possible.
my code ignter url

```
baseurl();index.php/registrtion/new_registrtion
```

while wordpress form is

```
www...........com/sineup.php
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I am reviewer of your question. You may wondering why in few days no one saw your post. I think the reason is you tagged it not correctly. Maybe you should add tags 'wordpress' and 'codeigniter'. Then people looking for question to answer in these categories will see your post and you will have a bigger chance to response.